# Invalid SRID in PostGIS when importing data by ogr2ogr

Tags: postgis, gdal, ogr, ogr2ogr

I am using PostgreSQL 12 with PostGIS 3.0.0 and GDAL 3.0.0 to copy data in it. The command I am using is:

```
ogr2ogr -f "PostgreSQL" PG:"host=127.0.0.1 dbname=db user=user
 port=5432 password=1" "file.geojson" -nln mutable
```

The issue here is when i check the SRID of the output table it is 900914 which is not correct in my case it should be  2223. To fix this i have to manually specify EPSG code by adding '-t_srs EPSG:2223'. This was not needed with previous version of ogr2ogr and PostGIS 2.5.

Comment: What does `ogrinfo` tell you about the source data? Can you show how exactly the SRID is defined in the source?

Comment: It would be safer to use `-a_srs` if you know for sure that it is correct. If GDAL happens to find some other and wrong crs from the data it will re-project the data with `-s_srs`.